# bootstrap datetimepicker not showing date when opened

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I'm using bootstrap-datetimepicker.  I have a button that sets the date and time on a datetimepicer div and it appears in the input correctly, but when I drop the calendar down, it shows the current month/year, not the date in the input.  But if I close the calendar and reopen it, the correct date is shows.  The calendar value is being set becuase when I drop the calendar the first time and go back one month, the correct date is highlighted.  How can I make the calendar show dates that are set programmatically?

Thank you.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/Libs/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Libs/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btnSetDate">Set Date</button>
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group date" id="dp1">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="testDate" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script src="Scripts/CalendarTest.js"></script>
```

My script is

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#dp1').datetimepicker(
    { format: 'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm A' }
).on('dp.change', function (ev) {
    var $div = $(this);
    var date = $div.data('date');
    $div.data("DateTimePicker").defaultDate(date);
    $div.datetimepicker('hide');
});

$('#btnSetDate').on('click', function () {
    var dateString = '2017/12/21 5:16 AM';    
    var date = new Date(dateString);
    var value = moment(date).format('YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm A');
    var $div = $('#dp1');
    $div.data("DateTimePicker").date(value);
});
});
```